# Remove unwanted attributes from an object in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object that has all the properties from the db from the call lets say:

```
u = User.find_by_email("email@email.com")
```

u has `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone` etc.

How can I get all attributes except `first_name` and `last_name` from the object itself, not by modifying the call to the model?

Comment: If you don't need attributes, you should omit them from your query. Fetching attributes you don't need wastes I/O on the database and wastes marshaling values on the Rails end. You are unlikely to notice the extra cost until you have enough data to measure aggregate performance.

Comment: I need the attributes, I just don't need them later on when i loop on the between them on a second stage, So for not calling the db again I am doing except.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
u.attributes.except("first_name", "last_name")
```

Comment: How can I delete 'first_name' from 'u' only, User object u with no first_name not Hash object with no 'first_name'.

Comment: you could always do `u.first_name = nil`.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably more future-proof to select the attributes you *do* want:

```
u.attributes.slice('email', 'phone')
```

Comment: they are too many so i cant slice all of them. i will try except though

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `delete` method on the object.

Example:

```
2.3.3 :001 > my_obj = { "name" => "name", "surname" => "surname" }
2.3.3 :002 > my_obj.delete("surname")
2.3.3 :003 > my_obj
=> {"name"=>"name"}
```