# Rails - Can't get only a few of the attributes for all objects in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Service that puts together an array of `Answer` objects, each containing a String for the answer text, a Boolean indicating whether it's the correct answer or not and it's id. This is my code so far:

```
@quiz.questions[current_question_index].answers
```

It works. I then take this array of answer objects and send it over an ActionCable channel to be displayed as buttons - that also works.

But now I'm thinking it would be better not to send the entire `Answer` objects (including the information which of the answers is correct), but only id and title so I tried to change my code according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037428/get-specific-attributes-from-an-activerecord-model):

```
@quiz.questions[current_question_index].answers.pluck(:id, :title)
```

This does not work for me - all my buttons now read "undefined". So I tried it another way according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110154/remove-unwanted-attributes-from-an-object-in-ruby):

```
@quiz.questions[current_question_index].answers.attributes.slice('id', 'title')
```

Now my buttons don't even get displayed anymore...

What I want is an array of objects that contain the attributes 'id' and 'title' from my retrieved `Answers`.

Can anyone give me any pointers to fix this? I'm a Rails beginner and would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said `answers` is an array, and `pluck` method is not available on the array (it's the [AR magic](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck))

And probably with the fix, your buttons stopped displaying because before you had an array of Answer objects, and now you have an array of hashes with keys: `id` and `title`.

You should check the inspector in your browser (F11 in chrome) to see what kind of Javascript errors you have and fix accordingly.

Sending hashes instead of full objects is a good idea, you just need to change the way you use them on the receiving end.

Edit:

Regarding attributes you need to do something like this

```
@quiz.questions[current_question_index].
  answers.map{|answer| answer.attributes.slice('id', 'title')
```

It will have  the effect you'd expect.

Regarding "Rails magic". What I meant was this: Rails don't call the query until the very last moment, instead you have an object `Answer::ActiveRecord_Relation` which allows you to call active record methods on it (`pluck` among them).

In your example you build an array of `Answers` and you can't call `pluck` on an array - it's just not defined.

I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation @meta. So I tried to use slice again and it gives me a NoMethodError for `attributes` :/ I kind of thought `attributes` was a Rails helper when I read the other Stackoverflow post, I don't actually have a model or anything named attributes...

Comment: And also: what is the _AR magic_? :) I checked the link, but I don't get what the difference is and why it's not available on arrays (even though I take your word for it).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you for explaining @meta, that is exactly what I was looking for. The only thing that still confuses me is `pluck` (which I'm not not using anyway but would like to understand better): I had previously been trying out `pluck` in the rails console like @max suggested in their answer, where it IS called on the answers collection and works. That is why I was confused when it didn't work in my code. That is the part I don't get yet...

Comment: I don't know how to put it differently. When you do `Answer.where(id: [1,2,3])` what you get in return is not an array, but `Answer::ActiveRecord_Relation` object. This gives you some extra methods like `pluck` or `to_sql`. You can iterate over this object and use it as an array, so it might be a little bit confusing. When you manually create `arr =  []; arr << Answer.new()` the `arr` is an array and it does not implement `pluck` method.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
question = @quiz.questions[current_question_index]
answers = question.answers.map { |a| a.attributes.slice('id', 'title') }
```

`#attributes` is a method on a model instance so you can't call it on an array or a collection. It returns a hash with string keys.

```
Answer.first.attributes
=> { id: 1, title: 'foo' }
```

If you want to same output as pluck (an array of arrays) then use:

```
.slice('id', 'title').values
```

However using a hash (which maps to an object in JS/JSON) is the better alternative.

`#pluck` on the other hand is a ActiveRecord method that works on a collection or scope since it creates a `SELECT foo, bar FROM baz` query and returns an array of arrays.

For example:

```
Question.find(1).answers.pluck('id', 'title')
=> [[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar']]
```

Comment: You can also use ActiveModel::Serializers or jBuilder to create JSON from your models.